# Repeat function constantly on mousedown

Tags: javascript

I am making a pen where you can shoot by just clicking or you can just hold, however I am unaware of how to make the event repeat over and over on hold.
you can see it here: http://codepen.io/TheAndersMan/pen/gwKmYy?editors=0111

But in order to keep it simple, I will just give an example:

```
document.querySelector("body").addEventListener("mouseDown", function() {
    console.log(123)
})
```

My hope is that I can set an interval, for it to do this every second or half second.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout)/[clearTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/clearTimeout) or [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval)/[clearInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/clearInterval). *Set* it on mousedown (or pointerdown) and *clear* it on mouseup (or pointerup).
Two examples ahead:

### Hold mouse to fire — Using setTimeout:

```js
const fireRate = 20;
let fireTimeout = null;

function startFire() {
  console.log("BAM!");
  fireTimeout = setTimeout(startFire, 1000 / fireRate);
}

function stopFire() {
  clearTimeout(fireTimeout);
}

document.addEventListener("mousedown", startFire);
document.addEventListener("mouseup", stopFire);
```

```css
html, body{height:100%;}
```

### Hold mouse to fire — Using setInterval

```js
const fireRate = 20;
let fireInterval = null;

function fire() {
  console.log("BAM!");
}

function startFire() {
  fire();
  fireInterval = setInterval(fire, 1000 / fireRate);
}

function stopFire() {
  clearInterval(fireInterval);
}

document.addEventListener("mousedown", startFire);
document.addEventListener("mouseup", stopFire);
```

```css
html, body{height:100%;}
```

Comment: Having firerate be in seconds (as a float) would be far more useful. It's not readily apparent that `fireRate = 20;` is 0.05 seconds, whereas `fireRate = 0.05;` makes it more obvious. Then instead of `1000/fireRate`, you'd use `fireRate * 1000`.

Comment: @MarkOrmston in war industry we count firerate as *Rounds*-per-second (RPS or eventually RPM...), so `firerate = 20` is quite obvious :D

Comment: The main issue I have with RPS, while generally being a more human way of looking at the problem, is that it breaks down to being not useful when you need something more unusual, such as 0.180s or the like (about halfway between 5RPS and 6RPS)... does 0.180s each action look like 5.5RPS? And if you've never had a client ask for that sort of rate, you're lucky!

Comment: @MarkOrmston If you need to use a Cyclic Rate of say 800 RP**M** for *say* assault rifles, than you can configure the interval accordingly to `1000*60 /fireRate` and set the weapon `fireRate` to that `800` instead. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rate_of_fire. And your client will be happy to adjust from 800 to 1200 if needed :D

Answer (score 2):

You can add an event listener for the [mousedown](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mousedown) event, and in the callback use [setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) to call the function at a set interval (e.g. 500 ms). Then observe [mouseup](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseup) and in the callback use [clearInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearInterval) on mouseup to clear the interval. see example below:

```js
var interval; //set scope here so both functions can access it
document.addEventListener("mousedown", function() {
  fireFunction();
  interval = setInterval(fireFunction, 500); //500 ms - customize for your needs
});
function fireFunction() {
  console.log(123); //replace with your code for firing 
}
document.addEventListener("mouseup", function() {
  if (interval ) {
    clearInterval(interval );
  }
});
```

Comment: What if we want to access the event from mousedown in the fireFunction? Passing the event to fireFunction only uses the first event fired.

Comment: Do you need some concurrent event instead of the first event (I.e. `mousedown`)? You could observe `mousemove` events...if you have a new question then you can post a new question and cite this one.